# Spark Streaming Direct Kafka Consumers are not evenly distrubuted across executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have created one sample Direct Kafka Stream in Spark. Kafka has 30 partitions of given topic. But all consumers are executing from same executor machine.

Kafka Manager screenshot.

[image]

As per my understanding in direct Kafka Stream, Driver gives the offsets to executors and polls with this.

**Spark Version: 2.4**

Sample code below:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingTest");

        conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "100");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "1");
        conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate", "1500");


        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(5));



        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<Object, Object>> kafkaStream1 = createKafkaStream(ssc, "test-topic-1");

        kafkaStream1.foreachRDD(rdd -> rdd.foreachPartition(p -> p.forEachRemaining(e -> {
            System.out.println("Processing test-topic-1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        })));

        kafkaStream1.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
            final OffsetRange[] beginOffsets = Arrays.stream(offsetRanges).map(o -> OffsetRange.create(o.topicPartition(), 0, o.fromOffset())).toArray(OffsetRange[]::new);
            rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
                OffsetRange o = beginOffsets[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];

            });
            ((CanCommitOffsets) kafkaStream1.inputDStream()).commitAsync(beginOffsets);
        });



        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }

    public static JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<Object, Object>> createKafkaStream(JavaStreamingContext ssc, String topic) {
        HashMap<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<broker-ids>");
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, topic+"hrishi-testing-nfr-7");
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 80000);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 10000000);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);

        return KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(), ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(ImmutableList.of(topic), kafkaParams));
    }
}
```

Comment: Dstream api is deprecated. Had you tried structured streaming?

Comment: Yes I know. Dstream is deprecated but my use case is very limited to map partitions only, so this is not a problem and can't afford migration at present. I doubt its because of Dstream.

Comment: You can map a dataframe as well. Anyway, please show full code, and this property looks suspicious `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs`

Comment: Added complete sample code @cricket_007

Comment: Looks like your code doesn't really do anything accept commit offsets. Have you tried just using a very basic property set? What are you trying to optimize for?

Comment: @cricket_007 This is just a sample code. My question is - why all consumers for this topic (it has 30 partitions) are consuming from a single machine. As per my understanding, Driver just gives the offsets to executors and executors poll data from Kafka. Does Driver fetch data from Kafka (for all partitions) and gives data to executors instead of offsets, then all the fetches will be sequential. I wanted to understanding what is going under the hood. We are building some framework on Kafka Streaming, which has scaling issues that's why I'm doing deep dive.

Comment: You mean Spark Streaming? Kafka Streams natively scales. Also, like I said, `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` is clearly set at 1, and you only have one node doing any work... Remove that property. And if you want sample code, just get a Dstream and print it to the terminal. Lose the offset stuff

Comment: @cricket_007 First of all, thank you for all the quick replies. 
Yes I mean Spark Streaming. `spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` I think the default for this config is 1 itself. Although I commented out the code and ran again but nothing, as Kafka manager was showing all consumers for 30 partitions were on the same machine with the same name. The second thing I don't think changing to this config will help (I increased from 1 to 4, didn't see any change). And it's better to not increase this as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23533736/445058.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208799/discussion-between-hrishikesh-mishra-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue it is happening because I was committing offset from driver. This the code.

**((CanCommitOffsets) kafkaStream1.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);**

```
   kafkaStream1.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
        rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
            partition.forEachRemaining(e -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("hrishi mess" + e);
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        });
        ((CanCommitOffsets) kafkaStream1.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
    });
```

Next, I enabled debug log on Executors and found that KafkaRDD was polling from Kafka it is clearly visible in the log.